# join a subquery in peewee

Tags: python, peewee

I'm stuck in converting below query into peewee :

```
SELECT bID, taskCount 
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        block.id AS bID,
        Count( task.id ) AS taskCount 
    FROM
        block
        LEFT JOIN task ON task.block_id = block.id 
    WHERE
        block.id NOT IN ( ( SELECT task.block_id FROM task WHERE task.channel_id = '1' ) ) 
    GROUP BY
        block.id 
    ) AS A
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT task.block_id FROM task GROUP BY task.block_id ) AS B
```

I know it can be done but I can't write complete solution because I don't know what to do with aliases (BID,TaskCount) and then where exactly use joins !

here's what I wrote , obviously it's not working:

```
subquery1 = (Block.select(Block.id.alias('BID'),fn.COUNT(Task.id).alias('TaskCount'))
 .join(Task,JOIN.LEFT_OUTER,Task.block_id == Block.id)
 .where(Block.id.not_in(Task.select(Task.block_id).where(Task.channel_id=='1')))
 .group_by(Block.id)
 .alias('subquery1'))

subquery2 = (Task.select(Task.block_id).group_by(Task.block_id) )
query = subquery1.select(subquery1.c.BID,subquery1.c.TaskCount)
 .join(subquery2, on=(subquery1.c.BID == subquery2.c.block_id))
```

EDIT : I fixed some errors. But now what should I get from query object ?!!
If I print query's rows I 'll face with :

```
peewee.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'subquery1.BID' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: Does the SQL you shared actually execute and do what you expect it to? It looks very broken to me.

Comment: Yes, although the sql code works fine, but I think it's written a bit non-standard!
Do not have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a little up and down I noticed a problem, there was an extra part in my code that I deleted it.

```
subquery2 = (Task.select(Task.block_id).group_by(Task.block_id) )
query = subquery1.select(subquery1.c.BID,subquery1.c.TaskCount).join(subquery2, on=(subquery1.c.BID == Task.block_id))
```

and the correct part is :

```
subquery1 = (Block
.select(Block.id.alias('BID'),fn.COUNT(Task.id).alias('TaskCount')
                 ).join(Task,JOIN.LEFT_OUTER,Task.block_id == Block.id)
                 .where(Block.id.not_in(Task.select(Task.block_id).where(Task.channel_id=='1')))
                 .group_by(Block.id)
                 .alias('subquery1')).order_by(fn.COUNT(Task.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are missing some information in the query to start with. You should specify:

- In the "from", whether the fields are coming from select statement A or B.
- In the "inner join", which fields you are using to map the select statements. for instance select A.*, B.* from B inner join A on B.field = A.field.

Im not familiar with Peewee myself but hopefully this will help.